# Consider the vector space $V = \{(a, 1 + a) | a\in\Bbb R\}$ with irregular definitions of addition and multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

with addition and scalar multiplication
defined by

$(a, 1 + a)\oplus (b, 1 + b) = (a + b, 1 + a + b)$

$k * (a, 1 + a) = (ka, 1 + ka), k\in\Bbb R$

find a basis for $V$.

I started off with taking the general form of any vector in $V$ but after that step I'm not sure how to split up the general form to get the vectors that form a basis.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** A basis is a maximal set of linearly independent vectors. Try to find a vector that is linearly independent and then expand the set. If it is impossible, you're done.

**Hint 2:** This is okay, because I already notice that the dimension is finite. Otherwise you may obviously fail.

Answer (score 1):

A basic of $V$ is $(1,1+1)$. Indeed, every vector $(a,1+a) \in V$ can be written $$(a,1+a)=a*(1,1+1).$$
In particular, $V$ is the vector space of dimension $1$. In the other words, $V \simeq \mathbb{R} $ (note that $V$ is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Comment: $V$ isn't a subspace of the plane, as they have incompatible additions and scalar multiplication.